# Run functions parallel in python 2.7 to use output of an function at the end of other functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallel-processing, python-multithreading

I am a newbie to python and never used it's parallel processing modules like `threading` or `multiprocess`. I am working on a real  time code problem where the output of one function is used as the input of one function. There is one big function which takes almost 3 seconds to complete. It is like a program where a person submit some documents to reception, and while his documents are being verified  he is directed to somewhere other for different checks. If at the end of these checks the result of documents verification is available then the program will be failed.

```
def parallel_running_function(*args):
     """It is the function which will take 3 seconds to complete"""
     output = "various documents matching and verification"
     return output

def check_1(*args):
    """ check one for the task"""

def check_2(*args):
    """ check two for the task"""

def check_3(*args):
    """ check three for the task"""

def check_4(*args):
    """ check 4 for the task"""


def main_function():

    output = parallel_running_function() # need to run this function 
                                        #parallel with other functions
    output_1 = check_1()
    output_2 = check_2()
    output_3 = check_3()
    output_4 = check_4()
    if output:
       "program is successful"
    else:
        "program is failed"

    I need the output of parallel running function is here along with the other executed functions. If I don't get the output of that function here then program will be failed or ll give some wrong result.
```

I am using python 2.7. I have read multiple posts about this problem `using threading`, `subprocess` and `multiprocessing` module of python but i couldn't get a concrete solution of this problem. What I got from other posts is seems i need to use `multiprocessing` module.  Can someone please give me an idea about how should i overcome of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import multiprocessing

pool = None

def parallel_running_function(*args):
     """It is the function which will take 3 seconds to complete"""
     output = "various documents matching and verification"
     return output

def check_1(*args):
    """ check one for the task"""

def check_2(*args):
    """ check two for the task"""

def check_3(*args):
    """ check three for the task"""

def check_4(*args):
    """ check 4 for the task"""


def main_function():

    res = pool.apply_async(parallel_running_function)

    res_1 = pool.apply_async(check_1)
    res_2 = pool.apply_async(check_2)
    res_3 = pool.apply_async(check_3)
    res_4 = pool.apply_async(check_4)

    output = res.get()
    output_1 = res_1.get()
    output_2 = res_2.get()
    output_3 = res_3.get()
    output_4 = res_4.get()

    if output:
       print "program is successful"
    else:
        print "program is failed"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    main_function()
```

The main process will block when get is called, but the other processes will still be running.

Comment: Thanks @eveatles for you answer, It is quite same i was looking for. But why `response.get()` is failing if the `parallel_running_function` is a member of a class or is an instance method. It is working fine with functions but creating problems with instance method.

Comment: It's because multiprocessing spawns new processes instead of threads. Because objects have an internal state that cannot be shared in memory across processes you have to use functions. If you really want to use methods, you can use threading instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer and response